# How to completely remove a runnable timer?

Tags: android, runnable, timertask

I have a timer which works great, it will output my Toast every 10 seconds. I thought I understood the following code quite well, but apparantly I do not as I cannot remove the timer, here is my code:

```
private void TimerMethod() {
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(Map.this, "You are going to " + destination,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

public void time() {

    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, timerAmount);
}
```

I tried:

```
myTimer.cancel();
```

But apparently this only does not affect any current running tasks, according to the help in Android. I tested it and it did not work.

I thought maybe I could do something with the runnable object `Timer_Tick` but there is not a lot I can do with it.

Overall I get lost in my posted code because I am not sure what does what now, I would appreciate an explanation on how to remove whatever part causes the timer to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own `Handler`, and `post()` your `TimerTick` to that. If you don't want your `TimerTick` to run, then just call `removeCallbacks()` on your `Handler`.

(I think that's what you're asking...)

Comment: Thanks James, I shall look into how to do this and give it a try, if I get stuck maybe you can show me an example of how to do this? Cheers!

Comment: This was actually quite easy to implement, thanks for the advice, I have it working fine now! :)